# Irregularities in Active Directory import with SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory-import

I have set up a brand new SharePoint 2016 farm and am attempting to get AD sync set up.  I have configured it using several online articles as guides and it appears to be working with a few notable exceptions:

1. Not all of my users are being imported.  I first ran a full sync and it imported ~350 users (of over 1000).  I have since run a number of full and incremental syncs and I am up to 640 users, but this is still not all of them.
2. None of my AD groups are available anywhere in the SharePoint site.  Any time I attempt to select a group (such as in setting up an audience or organization), none of my groups are available.

So far, I have done the following troubleshooting:

- Removed and rebuilt the User Profile Service
- Checked the ULS logs while performing a sync (no errors found)
- Checked the event log for errors (none found)

One thing that I did note in all of this is that the Profile Synchronization Status is always listed as Idle, even immediately after I start a sync.  The sync appears to work as more users are pulled in (usually only one or two at a time) and this may not have anything to do with anything.

I'm not sure what other information to provide or where to proceed from this point.  Anyone have any suggestions?

To answer the comment about our AD structure:  We have only one domain in our Active Directory.  Within that domain, I am selecting one OU.  This OU has six sub-containers and each of those sub-containers will contain three or four other subs (this mimics the organizational structure of our company).  Each of these OUs contains either users or security and/or distribution groups.  None of the users are disabled as disabled users are moved to a completely different OU.  The groups that I am interested in are set up as global groups.

Comment: are you using the ADI or external sync (MIM)?

Comment: I'm using the ADI sync.

Comment: On the sync connection page, when you enter credentials, domain name etc...at the bottom what you select (all or any single ou)...how many domains u have? How many different folders u have for users?